# FDF data not exporting fields from PDF (Adobe Acrobat)

Tags: pdf, acrobat, fdf

When exporting a PDF file using "Export Data" in Adobe Acrobat it almost always exports no field data in the FDF. The FDF data is missing despite the field names being set correctly in Acrobat. Occasionally this does work for documents but I can see no correlation between the ones that do work and the ones that don't.

Here, for example, is the PDF:
https://goodcms.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/staff_profile.pdf

But no matter what we do the FDF file is devoid of field name information, despite having field names in Acrobat: https://goodcms.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/staff_profile.fdf

This seems to happen with some PDFs and not others. The FDF flie is exported in the "export data" section of Acrobat, as outlined here https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/collecting-pdf-form-data.html

Love to get to the bottom of this - I've been trying to figure it out for months.

Comment: I don't have it at hand right now, but check the Acrobat JavaScript documentation for the exportAsFDF() method. I believe to remember that there is a parameter controlling whether all fields or only the filled ones are exported. (after having confirmed this, I may delete this comment, and add it as an answer)

Comment: Thanks - but - where, how and why would I need to run javascript within Acrobat, @MaxWyss? How do I execute this exportAsFDF() within Acrobat? Still doesn't help explain why the regular FDF export contains no data

Comment: The Acrobat JavaScript documentation also explains how to use the interactive Console in Acrobat. (you have to activate it in the Preferences, then you can access it with Cmd-J/Ctrl-J; enter the code, bring the cursor in the line you want to run, and press Cmd-/Ctrl-Return)